# I am trying to send data from browser to mobile application using stomp over websocket, but I faced an issue with the ip address

Tags: java, android, android-studio, websocket, stomp

I am pretty new to coding Stomp. My code is based on xlui/WebSocketExample on Github, I am successful in sending data from browser to android VM. However, I need to send data from the web browser to the android app on a mobile phone. I am currently using 10.0.2.2:8080 for Android VM, but if I use the app on my mobile phone, it will crash.

I have multiple questions on it:

- Do I have to change the IP address to my phone's IP address?
- Do the port number need to be changed?
- Do I have to use the same wifi on mobile and on the pc for it to work? I am currently using wifi for my pc and 4G for my mobile.

```
public class Const {
    public static final String TAG = "xlui";
    public static final String placeholder = "placeholder";

    /**
     * <code>im</code> in address is the endpoint configured in server.
     * If you are using AVD provided by Android Studio, you should uncomment the upper address.
     * If you are using Genymotion, nothing else to do.
     * If you are using your own phone, just change the server address and port.
     */
private static final String address = "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/im/websocket";//for android vm
    //public static final String address = "ws://10.0.3.2:8080/im/websocket";//for Genymotion 
    //public static final String address = "ws://localhost:9090/im/websocket";
    public static final String broadcast = "/broadcast";
    public static final String broadcastResponse = "/b";
```

```
public class BroadcastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button broadcastButton;
    private Button groupButton;
    private Button chatButton;

    private EditText nameText;
    private Button sendButton;
    private TextView resultText;

    private void init() {
        broadcastButton = findViewById(R.id.broadcast);
        broadcastButton.setEnabled(false);
        groupButton = findViewById(R.id.groups);
        chatButton = findViewById(R.id.chat);
        nameText = findViewById(R.id.name);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send);
        resultText = findViewById(R.id.show);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_broadcast);

        this.init();

        StompClient stompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, Const.address);
        StompUtils.lifecycle(stompClient);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start connecting to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Connect to WebSocket server
        stompClient.connect();

        // 订阅消息
        Log.i(Const.TAG, "Subscribe broadcast endpoint to receive response");
        stompClient.topic(Const.broadcastResponse).subscribe(stompMessage -> {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stompMessage.getPayload());
            Log.i(Const.TAG, "Receive: " + stompMessage.getPayload());
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                try {
                    resultText.append(jsonObject.getString("response") + "\n");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        });

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("name", nameText.getText());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            stompClient.send(new StompMessage(
                    // Stomp command
                    StompCommand.SEND,
                    // Stomp Headers, Send Headers with STOMP
                    // the first header is required, and the other can be customized by ourselves
                    Arrays.asList(
                            new StompHeader(StompHeader.DESTINATION, Const.broadcast),
                            new StompHeader("authorization", "this is a token generated by your code!")
                    ),
                    // Stomp payload
                    jsonObject.toString())
            ).subscribe();
            nameText.setText("");
        });




        groupButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(BroadcastActivity.this, GroupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        });
        chatButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(BroadcastActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. On same wifi. Use local ip address of phone. Port number is ok.

Comment: Before you can send data there should be a connection. Who is establishing a connection? And how?

Comment: `I am successful in sending data from browser to android VM.` ? I have no idea what you mean by that. Please explain scenario/set up.

Comment: I have a WebsocketServer set up, the data is input from a browser client to android studio virtual machine

Comment: If you want help you should not keep it that vague. Come to the point. Tell what you do.

Comment: Alright, i need a while to come up with what to say

Comment: I have a Spring Boot WebSocket Server, with a browser client and a simple Android client. The Android client uses StompProtocolAndroid which implements protocol STOMP on Android, to subscribe or send message to server. The browser client can be used to send messages to the android client vice versa.
The issue is with the address, I am unsure of what to change it to in order for the app to work on phone

Comment: Ehh... before that i wanted you to elaborate on `I am successful in sending data from browser to android VM.` How exactly are you doing that? And you named 10.0.0.2 hence we like to know who used that ip address. And from the two paried, who started the connection? Start with the connection. After that tell who is sending. And browser? Where is that browser running? On an Android device? Start with your setup.