# I am trying to send data from Browser to Android mobile App using STOMP and is facing issue with IP address

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, android-studio, spring-websocket

I am pretty new to STOMP, just learning it for a few weeks only. I have been trying for some time to send data from Browser to Android mobile App using STOMP, so far I have been successful in sending data from my browser to Android emulator, however if I try it on my mobile phone, the app will crash.

What I did:

- I ran the Spring Boot Websocket Server before running the Android studio emulator
- Used the same wifi for my phone and laptop where the server is run on.
- My code is based off of xlui/WebSocketExample. (Search on google and you can find the code)
- I am using NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid in Android Studio, the Android client uses StompProtocolAndroid which implements protocol STOMP on Android, to subscribe or send message to server.
- The Spring Boot WebSocket Server is ran on Intelliji full Version.
- changed from 10.0.2.2/8080/im/websocket to Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, "ws://MY LAPTOP IP ADDRESS/8080/im/websocket");

My Code in Android Studio for the Broadcast activity:

```
package app.xlui.example.im.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

import app.xlui.example.im.R;
import app.xlui.example.im.conf.Const;
import app.xlui.example.im.util.StompUtils;
import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.Stomp;
import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.StompClient;
import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.dto.StompCommand;
import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.dto.StompHeader;
import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.dto.StompMessage;

@SuppressWarnings({"FieldCanBeLocal", "ResultOfMethodCallIgnored", "CheckResult"})
public class BroadcastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button broadcastButton;
    private Button groupButton;
    private Button chatButton;

    private EditText nameText;
    private Button sendButton;
    private TextView resultText;

    private EditText nameput;
    private void init() {
        broadcastButton = findViewById(R.id.broadcast);
        broadcastButton.setEnabled(false);
        groupButton = findViewById(R.id.groups);
        chatButton = findViewById(R.id.chat);
        nameText = findViewById(R.id.name);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send);
        resultText = findViewById(R.id.show);
        nameput=findViewById(R.id.name2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_broadcast);

        this.init();

        StompClient stompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, "ws://MY LAPTOP IP ADDRESS/im/websocket");
        StompUtils.lifecycle(stompClient);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start connecting to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Connect to WebSocket server
        stompClient.connect();

        // 订阅消息
        Log.i(Const.TAG, "Subscribe broadcast endpoint to receive response");
        stompClient.topic(Const.broadcastResponse).subscribe(stompMessage -> {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stompMessage.getPayload());
            Log.i(Const.TAG, "Receive: " + stompMessage.getPayload());
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                try {
                    resultText.append(jsonObject.getString("response") + "\n");
                    nameput.setText(jsonObject.getString("response"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        });

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("name", nameText.getText());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            stompClient.send(new StompMessage(
                    // Stomp command
                    StompCommand.SEND,
                    // Stomp Headers, Send Headers with STOMP
                    // the first header is required, and the other can be customized by ourselves
                    Arrays.asList(
                            new StompHeader(StompHeader.DESTINATION, Const.broadcast),
                            new StompHeader("authorization", "this is a token generated by your code!")
                    ),
                    // Stomp payload
                    jsonObject.toString())
            ).subscribe();
            nameText.setText("");
        });




        groupButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(BroadcastActivity.this, GroupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        });
        chatButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(BroadcastActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        });
    }
}
```

My Code in Android Studio for the Const activity:

```
public class Const {
    public static final String TAG = "xlui";
    public static final String placeholder = "placeholder";

    /**
     * <code>im</code> in address is the endpoint configured in server.
     * If you are using AVD provided by Android Studio, you should uncomment the upper address.
     * If you are using Genymotion, nothing else to do.
     * If you are using your own phone, just change the server address and port.
     */
    private static final String address = "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/im/websocket";//for android vm
    //public static final String address = "ws://10.0.3.2:8080/im/websocket";//for Genymotion 

    public static final String broadcast = "/broadcast";
    public static final String broadcastResponse = "/b";
    // replace {@code placeholder} with group id
    public static final String group = "/group/" + placeholder;
    public static final String groupResponse = "/g/" + placeholder;
    public static final String chat = "/chat";
    // replace {@code placeholder} with user id
    public static final String chatResponse = "/user/" + placeholder + "/msg";

}
```

My Code in Android Studio for the StompUtils activity:

```
import android.util.Log;

import app.xlui.example.im.conf.Const;
import ua.naiksoftware.stomp.StompClient;

import static app.xlui.example.im.conf.Const.TAG;

public class StompUtils {
    @SuppressWarnings({"ResultOfMethodCallIgnored", "CheckResult"})
    public static void lifecycle(StompClient stompClient) {
        stompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(lifecycleEvent -> {
            switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {
                case OPENED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
                    break;

                case ERROR:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error", lifecycleEvent.getException());
                    break;

                case CLOSED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection closed");
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I do not know what I did wrong, I you have any suggestions please do say.

Comment: You have not even answered my questions here and just repeat the whole bunch as vague as you did before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69356514/i-am-trying-to-send-data-from-browser-to-mobile-application-using-stomp-over-web

Comment: I solved the issue, I just need to disable firewall.